# Background Service - Heap size

Tags: android, performance

I'm uploading the images from device to server in a background service, but when I open the app, it crashes (no logcat error). I'm using largeHeap="true" in manifest . What I wonder is how can I optimize a service ?

```
public String getGal(String sec)
{

    file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/Image/folder/");

    File[] allFiles = file.listFiles();
    for(int i=0; i<allFiles.length; i++) {


              try {
                  if(allFiles[i].getPath().toString().contains(".jpg"))
                  {
                  up(allFiles[i].getCanonicalPath()); //my upload method
                  }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

       }
    return sec;

    }
```

Comment: If there is "no logcat error", then on what basis are you claiming that "it crashes"?

Comment: Ops, my mistake, the app is saying "App isn't responding. Do you want to close it?" with a white blank screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the app is saying "App isn't responding. Do you want to close it?" with a white blank screen

You are tying up the main application thread. Note that lifecycle methods on a `Service`, such as `onStartCommand()`, are called on the main application thread. Any work that will take more than a millisecond or two should be moved onto a background thread.